# How can i burn a Windows 7 USB to an ISO?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, cd-burning

I'm trying to install Windows 7 from a USB onto a bootcamp partition. No working :(

So, I thought I might try and burn the bootable win 7 usb to a dvd or ISO (and then burn that ISO to disk).

How can I do this with my Macbook Pro? I al

Note: I'm using Lion, btw.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will probably be [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which lets you specify an ISO to use and will create a bootable USB drive from it. I've not tried it on Lion but a quick Google says it should be compatible (a 90% of the time it works all the time situation).

Comment: Hi Nicholas - um .. I don't think you read my question right? I've already got a bootable USB drive with Windows 7 on it. I need to make an ISO -from- the USB ...

Comment: Ah yeah my bad I misread it! The easiest way I know of is to use dd, the command will be: dd if=/dev/<your usb drive> of=win7.iso. You can then use that to create a DVD from either Disk Utility or Toast.

Comment: cheers :) I typed `df -h` to see my mounts, and saw the USB. Then i typed `dd -if=/dev/disk2s1 of=win7.iso` while in `terminal` and in my Desktop folder .. and get the error message: `dd: /dev/disk2s1: Resource Busy` .. :(

Comment: You need to make sure it's unmounted first or OS X won't allow you to write to it, try {hdiutil eject <diskname>}

Comment: Won't -write- to it? i'm trying to write the iso to my mac desktop, not back to the usb ... ?? And when i eject to the usb, it's not mounted so i can't access it anymore? (i just ejected it from FINDER). .. ????

Comment: Read from it even, sorry trying to multi-task badly. You actually have the command a little off, it should be if=/dev/disk2 rather than the full version, when you unmount it leaves just that reference to it, but you can do it without unmount (just double checked)

Comment: I would love to know this as well. It seems like everything out there on the internet has info about going bootable ISO to bootable USB stick, not the other way around. And while it's easy enough to make an iso with hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o Win7x64.iso /Volumes/Win7x64 the result isn't bootable like the stick is.